# Can I pipe lpt port over tcp?

Tags: networking, command-line, parallel-port

I'd like to pipe data in and out to a lpt (parallel IEEE 1284) port on another machine, to remotely use a device. Can it be done in a common unix-y system? I have ubuntu 12.04. :)

I was thinking something like:

machine A, terminal 1:

```
nc -l 1234 > /dev/lpt0
```

machine B, terminal 1:

```
nc 192.168.1.100 1234 < /dev/lpt0
```

and on second terminals:

machine A, terminal 2:

```
nc 192.168.1.100 4321 < /dev/lpt0
```

machine B, terminal 2:

```
nc -l 4321 > /dev/lpt0
```

I don't know if this is a sound way to do this.

**How to communicate with parallel ports remotely?**

Comment: NOTE: I have not enough reputation to create the `[parallel-port]` tag, even if the description for `[parallel]` says it should be used.

Comment: Created the tag for you, and retagged your question.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use CUPS?

Comment: @SourceLab yes, it's me assuming that a cnc device wouldn't classify as a printer and thus unusable via cups.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's posible - but not with the standard set of tools on a Linux installation.
The simplest solution is to use the [ppdev](http://people.redhat.com/twaugh/parport/html/ppdev.html) device driver and some custom code.